# Cannot deactivate APK with lower API level

Tags: android

My app is intended to only run on API level 20+.

Unfortunately my fist APK that I published was targeted towards API level 11+.

I fixed the issue and uploaded an updated version. Now I have two APKs that are active and published. If trying to deactivate one of them I am getting an error that downgrading is not allowed.

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution:

I had to deactivate an older APK from the beta-phase. After that I was able to deactivate the +11 APK.

Answer (score 0):

You should deactivate the oldest version so if version 1 is API 11+ and version 2 is API 20+ you should deactivate version 1. This should disable downloads for devices that are < API 20. If a lot of users have it installed you can't force them to update so you will have 2 version running until your whole userbase has update to that version.

Comment: When trying that I get an error message, about violating downgrade policy.